# How to Validate the data type of a field is it integer or string in AWS Glue in Scala and throw the errors of that invalid data

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I want to read data from s3 and applymapping to it and then write it to another s3.

I want to check by datatype in field wise whether the data match the mapping datatype or not.

Like in mapping I made username is string.
Now when I write it to a S3 I need to check whether username field has all string or it has some thing odd value.

How can I achieve it ?

any help would really appreciable to me.

Comment: I guess by writing some code to validate the strings...

Comment: in glue context which api method should I use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis.html

Comment: The scala-api you have referred is for low-level stuff, which is overkill for you use case. You should look into you specific transformation via UDF's - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-functions.html. Or depending on complexity of your validations, you might even not need UDF's, you can refer to this example - https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/DataCleaningLambda.scala